# jqgrid: get return value from json data

Tags: php, javascript

How can I get a return value from a json string?

For example, in the code below, how can I parse and read the variable `searchxx`?

**From PHP:**

```
$responce->page = $page; 
$responce->total = $total_pages; 
$responce->records = $BC->tot_count; 
**$responce->searchxx = $sSchWhere;
$responce->order = $sOrder;**

while ($data) ......

echo json_encode($responce);
```

**From HTML (Firebug):**

```
"page":"1","total":2,"records":"26",**"searchxx":"T0.NAME=pluto"** ,"order":"T0.NAME desc","rows":[{"id":"63025c7a-12ad-102c-bd62-005056801340","account_id":"c30c7934-e0f3-102b-8fd4-005056801340","actions":"","edtNAME":"Rossi Mario","edtACCOUNT_NAME":"<a href=\#\">Rossi Mario<\/a>","edtAREA":"DEMO","edtSTATUS":"Aperta","edtPRIORITY" ......etc.
```

---

I have this code:

```
jQuery("#list2").navGrid('#pager2'{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false})
       .navButtonAdd('#pager2',{   
       caption:"View Condition Where",    
       buttonicon:"ui-icon",    
       onClickButton: function(){

           alert($("#list2").getGridParam('searchxx')); **//Should output NULL**
           },     position:"last" });
```

How can I get the return value `searchxx` from jsondata?

Answer (score 1):

Convert JSON string into array using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Example:

```
$array = json_decode($your_json_string);
echo $array['searchxx']; // Should output "T0.NAME=pluto"
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon http://www.json.org/js.html should help. If not, check out libraries, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), 
[MooTols](http://mootools.net/), etc.